# chrome can not set -webkit-animation-name

Tags: google-chrome, css

My chrome auto update to V19.0.1084.46 m;and I got a horrible problem!

```
1.zetop('#id').css({'-webkit-animation-name':'pop'}); does not working!
2.el.style['-webkit-animation-name'] = 'pop';not working!
3.el.style.cssText +='-webkit-animation-name:pop'; not working!
```

I open the developer tool,and I see '-webkit-animation-name' has change to be '-webkit-animation'!

the only way is:

```
.pop{
-webkit-animation-name: pop;
}
el.classList.add('pop');
```

What is the problem with the new chrome?It this some kind of new standard of CSS3 or what??Obviously,with the new way,if I want to change an animation-name I have to remove the old style class,but what if I don't know the name of the style class that hold the animation-name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!I take it down!
just remove the property when the animation is over.

```
el.style.removeProperty('-webkit-animation-name');
```